# cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() is not working even though i have installed the library of it in pycharm window. what to do?

Tags: face-recognition, lbph-algorithm

I am trying to use '''cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()''' in my program but this error came **AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'** on pycharm. I had install all the following libraries required for this function but still no solution. I am this program on pycharm windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

> ```
> pip install opencv-contrib-python
> ```

and then try again. This worked for me